# How to estimate interest rate cut from futures contracts?

Tags: finance, compound-interest

I want to calculate the expected rate cut/change given futures contracts on the basic interest rate, knowing when the rate cut occurs (resembling the FED's FOMC). Consider compound rates and a 252 workday-year.

-DI1 is the interest rate's futures contract due to 7 workdays with an annual rate of 11.16% per year;
-DI2 is the interest rate's futures contract due to 27 workdays with an annual rate of 11.05% per year;
-The committee meeting occurs within 20 workdays. So the daily rate is constant until day 20 and, at day 21, the rate drops to a given target and remains constant until the maturity of the DI2 contract.

How to calculate the expected rate cut? Market expectations are close to a 0,5% annual rate cut (to 10.65% per year). I can work with the reverse calculation, but now without knowing the market expectations' cut.

Daily rates are calculated from effective rates. Consider the example from 11.15% per year:
$i_{daily}=(1+0.1115)^{1/252}-1$

I also tried to reverse the forward rates and isolating the $i_{newrate}$ as of:
$(1+i_{DI2})^{27/252} = (1+i_{DI1})^{20/252} * (1+i_{newrate})^{7/252} $

However, I'm dealing with average rates over an interval. I need the point estimate of the rate for the second period (from day 21 to 27).

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here.  Of course, the futures contract represents an integral over all the changes in the period.  So it includes some estimate for the cut, but these will be probability weighted.  That is, if spot is $1\%$ and I think there is a $50-50$ chance that the Fed will cut it by $.50$, I should price the future at $.75%$  But how could you hope to deduce the $.50$ from that?

Comment: We have the date of rate change (committee meeting in 20 days), so we can assume the rate change will occur after that day. Your questioning is also mine: maybe I can't calculate the most probable scenario, yet the probability weighted cut. That would also be of interest. Tks

Comment: In practice, people also look at option pricing.  Futures pricing along can't distinguish between the example I gave in my first comment and the scenario in which we know with absolute certainty that there will be a $.25$ cut, but options on the future will be priced very differently in the two scenarios.